# Multiple <html><body> </html></body> in same file

Tags: python, html

I have a multiple html files in one file:

```
<html> 
     <body> 
     </body> 
     </html> 

 <html> 
     <body> 
     </body> 
     </html> 

 <html> 
     <body> 
     </body> 
     </html>
```

and the result is that I get a messed up html file. How to correct this without removing tags from the rest. I am using python to generate the html file. If I use the `self.response.out.write(function(query))` I get a nice html page.

If I use it a second time `self.response.out.write(function(query2))` then the page gets distorted.

Comment: You need to escape the < and > characters in your question.

Comment: Why can't you remove the tags?

Comment: Can you post a short version of the HTML you get after the 2nd call?

Comment: _"If I use `write(html_document)`" I get a page, if I use it a second time the page is distorted"_ ...so only call it once? :) It feels to me like you are the cause of your problem here.

Comment: Yeah, why do you have multiple HTML files in one file in the first place? Wouldn't it be easier to remedy that?

Answer (score 3):

Have one HTML file per file. Anything else is invalid and won’t be processed properly.

If you’re not sure if your HTML files are valid, the [W3C’s validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will tell you.